# What algorithm is this Java code decrypting?

Tags: java, encryption

In something I am working on, Java code similar to the one below was found inside a decryption method:

```
//A char[] "key" and a ByteBuffer "input" already exists at this point.

int keyOffset = 0;
ByteBuffer output = ByteBuffer.allocate(Math.max(0, input.limit() - input.position())).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
int length = input.limit();

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    output.put((byte)(256 + input.get(i) ^ key[keyOffset]));
    keyOffset = (keyOffset + 1) % key.length;
}
```

While the fact that it is a decryption method can be determined from the class and method name, there is no description as to what kind of encryption it is decrypting, and that is what I want to ask in this question.

(I do not know who the original author of the code is so I cannot ask him/her.
There is a possibility that this is not a "known" encryption, but some sort of "original" encryption, I suppose. In that case I will settle for an answer that explains why that is likely)

Comment: apparently a simple XOR cipher

Comment: @njzk2 That's the answer, and you should post it as an answer.

Comment: If this encryption is protecting something valuable you should probably change it to a stronger method. The current approach is very weak (if the key is repeated many times).

Comment: @njzk2 Thank you! (It wasn't apparent to me, maybe I'm a n00b compared to you :)) As Jim Garrison said, if you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @Henry Thank you for the advice (In this case, the data is not something that can be accessed from the outside, nor sensitive data, so it's not a problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decryption is specifically this part:

```
input.get(i) ^ key[keyOffset]
```

Which is an XOR (the `^` operator is a binary XOR) between the input and the key (repeated, as the key is shorter than the input). You can find more about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher

The biggest risk in the XOR cipher is the plain-text attack, because `input ^ output == key`, so if someone can guess part of the message, then the key is instantly revealed, and the rest of the message with it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. May I ask you, what is the point of the `256 + ` in the code in my question? (Or maybe I should ask, is there a discernible point?)

Comment: it has to do with converting back to byte in the right interval. It depends on the type of your input.